# Homotopy Class of Maps from Euclidean Space

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $n,m\in \mathbb{Z}^+$, and let $\pi(\mathbb{R}^n,S^m)$ be the set of free homotopy classes from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $S^m$.  Is there more than one homotopy class in $\pi(\mathbb{R}^n,S^m)$?  In other words, is every continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow S^m$ null-homotopic?

**Edit:** What about the converse; i.e.: $\pi(S^m,\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^n$ is contractible. So there is a homotopy $h:\mathbb{R}^n\times[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^n$ taking the identity on $\mathbb{R}^n$ to a constant. Homotopies "compose" with functions in both directions. So we have a homotopy $fh:\mathbb{R}^n\times[0,1]\to S^m$ taking $f$ to a constant and a homotopy $hf:S^m\times[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow X$ be any continuous map where $X$ is any topological space. Then $(t,x) \in [0,1] \times \mathbb{R}^n \longmapsto f(tx) \in X$ is a homotopy between $f$ and the constant map to $f(0)$, so $f$ is null homotopic.

Similarly, let $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ any continuous map, then $(t,x) \in [0,1] \times X \longmapsto tf(x)\in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a homotopy between $f$ and the constant map to $0$. So $f$ is null homotopic.